# Does an extension of the B.E.S.T. theorem for multiple Eulerian circuits exist?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Given a directed multigraph $G=(V,E)$ (multiple edges and loops are permitted) the number of distinct Eulerian circuits for $G$ can be calculated with the B.E.S.T. theorem. Does a similar theory for splitting the graph into multiple circuits exist?

For prescibed $k,l \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\lvert E\rvert=k+l$, I am looking for the number of distinct pairs $(E_1,E_2)$ of Eulerian circuits $E_1,E_2 \subset E$ with the properties
$$
|E_1| = k \ ; \ |E_2| = l \ ; \ E_1 \cap E_2 = \emptyset \ ; \ E=E_1 \cup E_2 \ .
$$
In other words we want to count all possible ways of splitting the edges $E$ into two Eulerian circuits of prescibed length. This seems similar, yet more difficult than the setting of the B.E.S.T. theorem. Has this already been studied? Is there perhaps a way to reduce the problem back to the B.E.S.T. theorem? (Without having to sum over all possible ways to split the edges into two sets, which seems impractical for finding a formula or recursive property.)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Should be equivalent to counting the number of “returns” (times you get back to the vertex you started at) in usual Eulerian circuits, right?

Comment: Sorry, my formulation was a bit too unspecific. The vertices the Eulerian circuits return to need not be the same. For example a non-connected graph might be able to be split into two such Eulerian circuits.

Comment: Even still, putting aside the possibility of a disconnected graph, it should still be roughly like counting how many times you return to a vertex you visited before in an Eulerian circuit.

Comment: ok, I think I see what you mean. But one would need to be able to specify how many steps were between each 'visit' to the vertex. This does not seem as trivial as counting the total number of visits for a vertex within an Eulerian circuit. But it's more likely that someone has already developed the theory. Thanks for giving me a new direction to search!